# Rx.Js: understanding expand operator

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I post data to backend, processing data takes some time and long polling is not a solution in my particular case, so I send request each 5 seconds with `expand` operator

```
this.apiService.postData(data).pipe(
    expand((status) =>
        status.comptete? this.apiService.askStatus(status.request_id).pipe(delay(5000)) : empty()
    ),
    map((result) => {
        // processing result here
    })
);
```

The question is how can I make delay be dynamic (e.g. at first time I want to ask for status in 1 second, at second time in 2 seconds and so on)? And two more questions. Have I understood correctly that if I add `take(N)` operator that will limit `askStatus` calls to `N`? Have I understood correctly that I don't need to do any sort of unsubscription here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expand()` passes also index every time it calls the project function so you can calculate delay based on that:

```
expand((status, index) => 
  status.comptete ? this.apiService.askStatus(...).pipe(delay(...)) : empty()
```

Using `take(N)` inside `expand()` won't help because `expand()` calls the project function on every emission from both source and inner Observables. But you can of course use `take(N)`  after `expand()`.

You don't have to unsubscribe from `askStatus()` manually if you handle unsubscription later where you also subscribe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so if I do `take(1)` in place where I subscribe I'll need not do unsubscribe? And the thing that I really not understand is what's the need of doing unsubscribe here? All observables are http requests here, doesn't it mean that I don't need to do unsubscribe manually here?

Comment: `take()` just completes the chain which triggers unsubscription. So if you're using http requests everywhere they all complete automatically. `empty()` is an Observable that just completes. If you want to see that the chain is being unsubscribed you can use for example this: `source$.subscribe().add(() => console.log('...'));` Function `add()` will add a dispose handler to the `Subscription` object returned.